# Identify laptop display vs external monitor programmatically in C++

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm IT for my company and multiple of our user know very little of computers. We have multiple drop-in stations with docks and external monitors. So users experience display issues when moving to a different station. Monitors resize, duplicate or change frequencies.

I made this easy to use one click tool to resize their monitors in a console C++ exe. The issue I run into is identifying whether the display is a laptop display or an external monitor. This is important because all of our external monitors are 1920 x 1080 but some of our laptops are 1920 x 1200.

**main.cpp:**

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
int main()
{

    DEVMODE devmode;
    
    SetDisplayConfig(0, NULL, 0, NULL, SDC_TOPOLOGY_EXTEND | SDC_APPLY);
    

    //long result = ChangeDisplaySettings(&devmode, 0);

    DISPLAY_DEVICE displayDevice;
    displayDevice.cb = sizeof(displayDevice);
    int deviceIndex = 0;
    while (EnumDisplayDevices(0, deviceIndex, &displayDevice, 0))
    {
        std::wstring deviceName = displayDevice.DeviceName;
        int monitorIndex = 0;

        while (EnumDisplayDevices(deviceName.c_str(), monitorIndex, &displayDevice, 0))
        {            
            devmode.dmPelsWidth = 1920;
            devmode.dmPelsHeight = 1080;
            devmode.dmDisplayFrequency = 60;
            devmode.dmFields = DM_PELSWIDTH | DM_PELSHEIGHT | DM_DISPLAYFREQUENCY;
            devmode.dmSize = sizeof(DEVMODE);

            long result = ChangeDisplaySettingsEx(deviceName.c_str(), &devmode, NULL, NULL, 0);
            ++monitorIndex;
        }
        ++deviceIndex;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you are looking for the `DISPLAY_DEVICE_REMOVABLE` flag in the `displayDevice.StateFlags` field?

| Value | Meaning |
| --- | --- |
| DISPLAY_DEVICE_REMOVABLE | The device is removable; it cannot be the primary display. |

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/ns-wingdi-display_devicea

Comment: I suspect the documentation is old. Because yes, it seems like that [happened](https://groups.google.com/g/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.gdi/c/Squ66KGc5_g) to be true at least once upon a time in the past, but on all my W10 laptops I can set external monitors as primary without batting an eye (both when I use "Show only on 2" and when I put them on "Extend" - and regardless or whether there are switchable graphics quirks or not). It may mean nothing (i.e. new drivers are just more flexible and less picky), but it may also be that the flag has lost its meaning to begin with...